# VS Express (C#) difference between Properties>Resources.resx and Resources1.resx

Tags: c#, visual-studio, project

I am curious what is the difference between those two? I was able to add resources to both of them. In the project properties menu, when I click on resources, the content of the first one is displayed. Why there are by default both? The same with settings. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio turns to suggest you store all resources into Properties>Resources.resx. But you can feel free to add your own resources, such as Resources1.resx in the project folder. They will be compiled separately, and does not conflict with each other.

But it is a good practice to use only one resx file per project IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

Properties>Resources.resx is the default (global) resource folder. Your Resources1.resx is only a reference to it. Unless you've defined another resource folder manually.

Comment: So how it comes that when I add something to that global one, it doesnt appear in the Resource1?

Comment: They are two stand alone files.

Comment: Then I do not understand how it could be reference, as Pieter said.